# Add institution logo to presentation slides

Tags: beamer, logos

I please want to include the logo of my institution at the top right of my first slit of my presentation at the bottom slit of my presentation. How should i go about this?

Comment: Without a crystall ball it's complicated to say. Did you have any code sample of your presentation?

Comment: Search in this site "beamer \logo" for a endless list of questions about the logos in presentations. Sure that you will find the right answers here. Otherwise, edit the question to post a minimal working example (MWE) showing how far you can get with this issue. Then people will be more able/willing  to help.

Answer (score 1):

How to position a logo at the bottom of normal frames is pretty good covered by the duplicates I proposed. For the title page you could use a little trick to place the logo at the top right:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\logo{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-duck}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\hfill\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}

\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]